# Ejecutar macro vba solo después de actualizar consulta

Tags: vba

Necesito ejecutar una macro después de actualizar una consulta de excel. Lo qie necesito es que se actualice la consulta y una vez cargados los datos de la misma que se ejecute el resto de la macro. Estoy usando:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MiConsulta").Refresh
```

Pero quiero que el resto del código se ejecute hasta que la actualizacion se finalice y haya cargado todos los datos en la hoja de excel.
Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando es `DoEvents`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MiConsulta").Refresh
DoEvents
```

Lo que hace `DoEvents` es devolverte de forma temporal el control sobre el libro, en este caso al hacerlo después de la actualización de datos, la macro no continuará hasta que ésta termine.

Answer (score 0):

Solución a tu problema:

Es simple. Configurar la consulta de forma distinta a como está configurada por defecto:  (Ficha Datos/Consultas y conexiones/Botón derecho sobre la consulta/Propiedades/Desactivar la opción Habilitar actualización en segundo plano)